# Не сработал декремент Redis в Node.js

Tags: node.js, node-redis, redis

```
redis_cli.decrby("USER:UNREAD:" + data.idUser, function (err, Ctr) {
 console.log(Ctr); //underfuned
});
```

Кто сталкивался?

Comment: Спасибо - решено!

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (err)
{ console.log(err);} 
else 
{console.log(Ctr);}
```